# Select a dummy column with a dummy value in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following

```
Table1
col1   col2
------------
 1      A 
 2      B
 3      C
 0      D
```

Result

```
col1   col2  col3
------------------
0       D     ABC
```

I am not sure how to go about writing the query , col1 and col2 can be selected by this

```
select col1, col2 from Table1 where col1 = 0;
```

How should I go about adding a col3 with value ABC.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try this:

```
select col1, col2, 'ABC' as col3 from Table1 where col1 = 0;
```

Comment: How to do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: It works on PostgreSQL, just use simple quote for the value, no double-quote.

Comment: lovely, because i need this on datatables ci3, to select random not ambigous column

Comment: working on MySQL version: 5.5.5-10.4.14-MariaDB

Answer (score 13):

If you meant just ABC as simple value, answer above is the one that works fine.

If you meant concatenation of values of rows that are not selected by your main query, you will need to use a subquery.

Something like this may work:

```
SELECT t1.col1, 
t1.col2, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col2 SEPARATOR '') FROM  Table1 t2 WHERE t2.col1 != 0) as col3 
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.col1 = 0;
```

Actual syntax maybe a bit off though

Comment: and if this is the case, that SQL will not work in all databases, SQL Server does not have Group_concat. But it looks like it should work for mysql

Comment: your ans helped me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041668/adding-one-more-column-externally-in-query?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Yeah, I hate the accepted answer. In DB2, I think listagg is the equivalent function.

Answer (score -2):

select '' as "Attribute",* from  will work simply

Comment: select '(value)' as "Attribute",* from (table) will work simply

Comment: This answer brings nothing new in comparison to the accepted answer (it is in fact less clear), has no formatting to make it easy to read and the example posted is not even valid since it is missing the table in the `FROM` clause... What even is the point of posting that 14.5 years later?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).